# sphinx-apidoc does not include a sub-package in the generated files

Tags: python, python-sphinx, sphinx-apidoc

My directory is as follows (with the proper `__init__.py` files not listed here):

```
root
    package1/
        subpackage1/
          submodule1.py
        module1.py

    package2/
        module2.py

    docs/
```

Running `sphinx-apidoc . --full -o docs -H 'MyProject' -A 'MyName' -V '1.0'` I get almost everything I need:

- `index.rst`
- `package1.rst`
- `package1.subpackage1.rst`
- `package2.rst`

`index` does list `package1` and `package2` **but** `package1` does not list `package1.subpackage1`.

I don't want to manually edit `package1.rst` as it's not scalable for a large project to manually list every sub package.

Comment: If I read the question correctly, you want to index files generated, one at the root level, and a second at the package1 level, correct? In any case, you can fiddle with the [options for `sphinx-apidoc`](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/man/sphinx-apidoc.html#options).